# Android java set image Resource

Tags: java, android

I get a force close on this

```
if(num1.getText().equals("0")) {
            num1.setText("1");
            ImageView hpdown1  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hair);
            hpdown1.setImageResource(R.drawable.haie2);
        }
```

Please help..

Comment: I suspect there'll be an exception somewhere in a log. Find it and it'll give a lot more information...

Answer (score 20):

You can use getDrawable method from Resources class. For example :

```java
ImageView image  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Resources res = getResources(); /** from an Activity */
image.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage));
```

Comment: To support older versions use ResourcesCompat like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29041466/1732338

Answer (score 3):

**Is deprecated**

```
getResources().<strike>getDrawable</strike>(R.drawable.myimage));
```

**Now:**

```
image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.menu_southamerica));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say, but I'm guessing a null pointer exception. Make sure that `hpdown` is not `null` before you call setImageResource.

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me that your issue is that your resource is: R.drawable.haie2 which to me, in the context of your code, looks like it's a spelling mistake that is supposed to be R.drawable.hair2